# Is Graph Database a good use case for a messaging system?

Tags: graph, chat, graph-databases, orientdb

I am diving in the universe of Graph Databases and I'm simply amazed by how powerful it is. I chose OrientDB to start my first use case but I'm not certain if my domain applies to this specific section of my App.

---

An **User** *follows* another **User**.

An **User** can *be part of* a **Conversation**.

A **Message** can be *sent* (with a timestamp) to a **Conversation**.

A **Message** can be *read* (with a timestamp) by an **User**.

---

I'm worried to end up with millions (even billions) of **Message** nodes and *sent* or *read* edges thus affecting the overall performance of the system. The messaging section is not the main concept of the app, it is just a *small* portion of it.

Would it be a problem for OrientDB to handle? Is it a good application for a Graph Database?

Thank you all for your patience,
Vinicius

Answer (score 3):

Don't think a Graph Database is a best candidate for a messaging system. Message system are relational in nature and suits the likes my MySQL.

You wouldn't be surprised to hear though that Facebook uses document-oriented databases for their messaging system.

Facebook is currently the largest installation of Cassandra, which is excellent for scalability. We already know that from Facebook. Plus its great for storing messages due to its distributed nature.

Comment: Ali, thank you for your answer! Please check out my comment on @Kikohs answer

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the suggested way to use OrientDB with a similar use case:

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Chat-use-case.html

Answer (score 2):

The choice of a graph database ultimately depends on what are you going to do with the data.
In your case, do you plan to use any graph-processing algorithms, or graph traversals?

An edge in graph theory represents a relationship between nodes (objects). In the case of a timestamp for read and sent, it does not really fit and you will end up with billions of edges, killing the performance of the system.

The follower concept perfectly fits the database. Now concerning the Conversation it could be an attribute of the node. Do you need to create an edge to represent ownership **just to query** the Conversation ID ?

If the messaging is just a small part of your application, I suggest to use the best tool for your need and to **combine** both a column-oriented database (Cassandra) and use Orient-DB to represent relationships or use Orient-DB as in the [Chat use case](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Chat-use-case.html) (Thanks @Lvca)

> What we suggest is to avoid using Edges or Vertices connected with
>   edges for messages. The best way is using the document API by creating
>   one class per chat room, with no index, to have super fast access to
>   last X messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am planning to do an hybrid solution after reading the article @Lvca sent and Ali Gajani's answer. As OrientDB also supports Documents, I'm thinking to embed the messages into the Conversation and only create edges between Users and Conversations. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

Also wondering about this topic but I think any `RDBMS` will be better for this task.

Also, Chat is kinda of a **log**. So `ElasticSearch` (and similar) can be perfect match for storing Terra bytes of chat data.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of dissonant answers here.. Speaking from experience, I've built a few messaging systems on plain **MongoDB** instances with no issues whatsoever handling hundreds/thousands of concurrent users (with chat groups).

I'd say go with either Cassandra as it's a battle-tested database if you're very worried about scalability (as it's got it practically built-in) or some of the newcomers like MongoDB which is constantly being upgraded and you can relatively easily then include search via *ElasticSearch* on top of that. MongoDB supports scaling via *sharding* and it can therefore horizontally scale to your needs. 
Just be sure to **not bottleneck your speed on your backend service**, implement as much asynchronous operations as possible.

Now, you can even go as far as to implement a streaming platform like Kafka which is excellent for CDC (*change data capture*) and will persist your message log until it is read by a service that actually writes messages to your database of choice, adding to your resiliency factor.